# RoR testing controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use RoR 3 and i guess something changed in controller's tests.

There is no

```
def test_should_create_post
```

but

```
test "should create user" do
...
end
```

Is there any decription how is that mapping etc? Because i dont get it.

And second thing. How to program (what assertion) use to test login?

Answer (score 1):

so the `test "something here"` style is rails way of helping us out.  It is fundamentally the same as `def test_as_you_want` but they helped us out by taking away those nasty '_(underscores)' and wrapping the actual test wording in a string.  This change came back, phew... maybe 2.3.x. that fact has to be checked but at least a year and a half ago.

Your second thing is a little more harder to answer man.  What plugin are you using, or are you one of those guys who are writing their own auth system?

Either way,  check out  how the 'famous' auth plugins do it.  from Restful Auth to Devise, basically you want test that you can:

1. Signup for the User account
2. all of your confirmation emails are sent etc..

Most of these 'cheat' or take the easy way out by passing a helper called `signed_in users(:one)` for instance.  Assuming you are cool and using fixtures.

Basically here is what a helper method looks like if your Auth plugin/gem doesn't have one, like Clearance which didn't  have it when i was first writing my tests... not sure if it has it now but it sheds light on how it should look.  Notice I've commented out Restful Auth and how he/they did it:

```
  #login user
def login_user(user = users(:one))
  #Restful Auth Example
  # @request.session[:user_id] = user ? users(user).id : nil
  # Clearance
  @controller.class_eval { attr_accessor :current_user }
  @controller.current_user = user
  return user
end
```

Actually i think i stole this from their shoulda login helper... that's probably what i did.  Either way it shows you how to fake login a user.

Now when you are testing, just pass this login_user method to your test when  you need a user logged in and start testing the rest of the method without worrying about them actually signing in.  That is what the plugin is supposed to do and the 1000 people following it on github would scream if it didn't at least LOG that guy in.

cheers

Comment: I write my own auth system, it's very simple, auth method in model, singup, login actions and simple views. Its all i need. 

I need to:

send post request to login action once with good data and once with bad ones. And check if session variables are setted. And i dunno how to achieve last thing.

Comment: So your real question is "How do I test that my session variables are being set"?